# Return string instead of class in Python

Tags: python, class, return, instance

Hi in a recent local programming contest there was a problem in which you had to define a class which takes chain-like parameters and returns their sum e.g. :

```
>>> Chain(2.5)(2)(2)(2.5) # sum
9
>>> Chain(3)(1.5)(2)(3) # sum
9.5
```

Best thing that I could write is this code:

```
class Chain():

    value = 0

    def __new__(self, num):
        self.value += num
        return self

obj = Chain(2)(3)
print(obj.value)
```

But the return type is a class not an int, furthermore I'm using a static property which is obviously wrong. Would appreciate any helps.

P.S. : Please note that that contest finished on January 7 2022 so I don't think there is any problem with posting this question.

Comment: You'll want to look at the `__call__` and `__str__` methods, not `__new__`…

Comment: @deceze Thanks I could write the answer using your suggestion. I also changed the title to represent the question and the answer better. However I'm not sure whether I should delete the question (since it has no answer and your comment is the correct answer) or keep it. Maybe a better title for the question can make it useful to others who may face the same problem

Comment: @AvSaba please provide the working code

Comment: @sahasrara62 Yes your link answers the question. It's interesting that the question was asked the same day that the contest happened.

Comment: @AvSaba no idea about what context you are talking, but i have seen this question so marked it as duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit from `float` (as you need to support decimal numbers) and implement `__call__` like so:

```
class Chain(float):
    def __call__(self, value):
        return self.__class__(self+value)

>>> Chain(3)(1.5)(2)(3) # sum
9.5
>>> Chain(2.5)(2)(2)(2.5) # sum
9.0
```